# How to transform th function into decorator in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the fucntion header which values I need to put into 3 urls, I don't want to request the values in every view and render the context, because it takes some lines.
 How can I make the decorator?

```
def acc_profile(request):
    refferals, balance= header(request)
    context = {'refferals':refferals,'balance':balance}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html')

def header(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    refferals = Customer.objects.filter(name_id=user_id).values("refferals").first())['refferals']
    balance = Customer.objects.filter(name_id=user_id).values("nickname").first())['nickname']
```

How can I make the def header into decorator and upper def acc_profile just put @header for example

Answer (score 0):

You can create decorator like this

```
def acc_profile(request, referrals,balance):
    context = {'refferals':refferals,'balance':balance}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html')

def header(func):
  def fun(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = request.user.id
    refferals = Customer.objects.filter(name_id=user_id).values("refferals").first())['refferals']
    balance = Customer.objects.filter(name_id=user_id).values("nickname").first())['nickname']
    return func(request, referrals, balance,*args,**kwargs)
  return fun
```

Also if you don't want to pass referrals and balance to function then you need to store somewhere.
According to me, we can store them in `request.session`